# Python query to game server

Tags: python, django, udp, minecraft

I am trying to query a Minecraft server using a python class written by Dinnerbone (one of the developers of the game). When I try to query it, I get the error "A message sent on a datagram socket was larger than the internal message buffer or some other network limit, or the buffer used to receive a datagram into was smaller than the datagram itself". From what I can understand, it seems this could be a physical limit of UDP itself.

I am not entirely sure what is causing this or what I can do about it.

The class can be found here: https://github.com/Dinnerbone/mcstatus/blob/master/minecraft_query.py

Any advice is appreciated as the error does not show in a command prompt window however it does error when running via Django.

Comment: Your gut feeling is most likely correct. UDP is limited by the physical layer datagram size. The error might be that there is a mismatch between actual bytes wired and packetsize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is that the script is trying to read the packet into a buffer that is too small to hold it. This seems to be happening on line 42 in the script:

```
buff = self.socket.recvfrom(1460)[0]
```

Try changing the buffer size from 1460 to something larger.